# How to measure the total capacity of a table in MySQL and SQLite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, size

I want to measure - if not accurate - the capacity that a table caught in a database in MySQL case and in SQLite respectively in Java.

Example:
Table size : 25kb

How can I succeed at that?